# IP Conflict in the Network

Tags: ipv4

I am not a Network administrator, but i am having a IP Conflict in one of the system that uses Static IP (A Application Server), other systems are given Dynamic IP addresses.

I just want to know which PC is causing IP Conflict so that i could just switch it off till the Network administrator comes and remove the error, and I could continue my development work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not mentioning what kind of hardware you're using, I can only give a general way of approaching this:

Try finding out the MAC addresses of the hosts using the duplicate IP address. You can sometimes find this in log entries of the host which address has been 'stolen' or in router logs. If this doesn't work you can try looking in ARP tables of various machines in your network and compare the output for the problematic IP address.

Now, you should have two different MAC addresses claiming to belong to the same IP address. You do a vendor lookup on a site like http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/. This can help you identify the brand of the two hosts, which may help you to narrow down your search.

If you have managed switches, you can do lookups on these switches to find out on which port these MAC addresses are being used by looking at the forwarding tables. This should help you find the port to which the problematic host is connected.